# Доступ к конструктору класса только из одного класса в другом пакете

Tags: java, рефлексия

Есть 2 отдельных пакета и в каждом по 1му классу (условно 1c и 2c)

Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы в 1с происходило что-то вроде

```
Class cls = Class.forName(2с.getClass().getName());
Object instance = cls.newInstance();
```

Для этого нужно, чтобы в 2с был public(!) конструктор без параметров. Но загвоздка в том, что нужно, чтобы экземпляр 2c создавался только в 1c и нигде больше (но если конструктор 2с public, создать экземпляр можно в любом месте приложения)

Как это реализовать?

П.С. в один пакет их положить нельзя и кусок с рефлексией убрать тоже

Comment: Никак. Нет в Java "дружественных" пакетов, равно как и подпакетов. Хотя можно попробовать `setAccessible`. Но это, опять же, из серии "либо все, либо никто".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас какая то рефлексия не полная, применив настоящую рефлексию можно вытащить даже приватный конструктор:

```
  Constructor[] cons = SecondClass.class.getDeclaredConstructors(); 
  cons[0].setAccessible(true); //может выкинуть исключение, если установлен SecurityManager
  SecondClass secondClass = (SecondClass)cons[0].newInstance();
```

Comment: Вместо `getDeclaredConstructors()[0]` в данном случае лучше воспользоваться `getDeclaredConstructor()`, чтобы точно попасть в нужный конструктор.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант решения:

```
public class A {
    private static final A instance = new A();

    private A() {
    }

    public A getInstance(Object o) {
        return o instanceof B ? instance : null;
    }   
}
```